# Re-bind a Random Number Generator in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I've got a function in Clojure which generates random numbers via `rand`:

`core.clj`:

```
(ns my-lib.core)

(def my-rand rand)

(defn my-fn []
  (take 3 (repeatedly my-rand)))
```

I'd like to test it, but it's hard since I don't know what to expect. Is there a way that I could re-bind `core/my-rand` such that it makes testing easier? Something like this:

`core_test.clj`:

```
(ns my-lib.core-test
  (:require [clojure.test :refer :all]
            [my-lib.core as core]))

; i'd like to re-bind the my-rand function here to make testing easier, but this doesn't work
(def core/my-rand (constantly 1))

(deftest my-fn
  (is (= (core/my-fn) '(1 1 1))))
```

Alternatively, is there a more idiomatic way of doing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `with-redefs` for this:

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/with-redefs

```
(deftest my-fn-test
  (with-redefs [core/my-fn (constantly 1)]
    (is (= (repeatedly 3 core/my-fn) '(1 1 1)))))
```