# How to generate repeatable random sequences with rand-int

Tags: clojure

I want to be able to generate repeatable numbers using `rand` in Clojure.  (Specifically, I want results of calls to `rand-nth` or Incanter's `sample` to be repeatable, and these call `rand-int` which in turn calls `rand`).

I figured out from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22441860/why-doesnt-repeatedly-generate-reproducible-random-numbers-when-using-a-seed-in) that if I use clojure.data.generators, I can reset the random state:

```
(require '[clojure.data.generators :as gen])
(alter-var-root #'gen/*rnd* (constantly (java.util.Random. 437)))
(gen/reservoir-sample 5 (range 1000)) ; => [940 591 636 12 755]
(gen/reservoir-sample 5 (range 1000)) ; => [376 540 827 307 463]
; reset random state:
(alter-var-root #'gen/*rnd* (constantly (java.util.Random. 437)))
; now the same results are generated again:
(gen/reservoir-sample 5 (range 1000)) ; => [940 591 636 12 755]
(gen/reservoir-sample 5 (range 1000)) ; => [376 540 827 307 463]
```

However, that method only seems to affect functions in clojure.data.generators, which isn't surprising:

```
(alter-var-root #'gen/*rnd* (constantly (java.util.Random. 437)))
(rand) ; => 0.9372552374760151
(rand) ; => 0.2712729314667742
; reset random state:
(alter-var-root #'gen/*rnd* (constantly (java.util.Random. 437)))
; not same results as before:
(rand) ; => 0.630238593767316
(rand) ; => 0.426744420572015
```

How can I restore the random state in such as way as to get repeatable results from `rand`?  So far I haven't found any documentation about this.

([Another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22429778/re-bind-a-random-number-generator-in-clojure) sounds as if it might be the same issue, but it's asking about something completely different.)

Comment: When you say repeatable sequences, do you want an actual Clojure seq? That's fairly easy. Otherwise, you will probably want your own random number generator function that can be created with a specific seed (or no seed at all) that wraps either java.util.Random or java.secure.Random.

Comment: @Bill, thanks--No, I don't need Clojure sequences.  I just want to preserve the order of results of calls to `rand`.  I couldn't think of another brief way to express this in the question title.

Comment: I posted an example of what I was talking about. In some ways it doesn't answer your question. I don't think that they really design in a hook for you to muck about with core.rand, so I wouldn't approach it that way. If you're stuck because there's a lot of code that's out of your control that calls core/rand, then maybe something like roberthooke might help. https://github.com/technomancy/robert-hooke/

Comment: UPDATE 2020: While my question and some of the answers still seem potentially useful, I stopped using Clojure's `rand` a long time ago, not only because `java.util.Random` couldn't easily be seeded, but because was it not a sufficiently high-quality pseudorandom number generator for my purposes (agent-based simulations).  I usually use [Sean Luke's Java implementation of the Mersenne twister algorithm](https://cs.gmu.edu/~sean/research).  I don't consider the Mersenne tiwster to be state of the art, but still quite good if you throw away the first 2K numbers after seeding the class instance.

Comment: Recent versions of Java have some PRNGs that are better than the old `java.util.Random` that was available when I posted my question, I believe.

Answer (score 4):

Probably not the cleanest way, but you can make it work by redefining `clojure.core/rand`:

```
(ns clojure.core)

(def r (java.util.Random. 1))

(defn rand
  ([] (.nextDouble r))
  ([n] (.nextInt r n)))

(take 10 (repeatedly #(rand-int 10)))
```

This produces (5 8 7 3 4 4 4 6 8 8) every time I run it.

Comment: Your answer and @Bill's comment suggest that Clojure really hasn't addressed this common need at the Clojure level, and that in the end one is expected to descend to Java for this kind of thing.  `rand`, etc. are just convenience functions, then.  Kind of surprising to me.  Maybe Clojure has been used more in business processes than in science, where the need for repeatable random behavior is commonplace.

Comment: The philosophy of Clojure is to not attempt to hide the fact that it's running on a host, in this case the JVM. "Descending to Java" is not a bad thing, especially because Java interop is so easy. Also, Clojure is a relatively young language. If a use case becomes common enough, someone will write a pure Clojure library to do what you need. I agree that Incanter should support repeatability directly, and I'd file an issue.

Comment: Thanks Diego.  I agree.  One of the things that's great about Clojure is that it's so easy to use Java from it.  I'll go ahead and file an issue with Incanter, and will bring it up for discussion on on the Clojure Google group.

Comment: This answer would be improved by adding a mechanism to set the random number seed.

Answer (score 4):

A clean way:

```
(ns designed.ly.rand)

(def ^:dynamic *rand* clojure.core/rand)

(defn rand-1
 ([]
   (*rand* 1))
 ([n]
   (*rand* n)))

(defmacro with-rand-seed
 "Sets seed for calls to random in body. Beware of lazy seqs!"
 [seed & body]
  `(let [g# (java.util.Random. ~seed)]
     (binding [*rand* #(* % (.nextFloat g#))]
      (with-redefs [rand rand-1]
        ~@body))))
```

It redefines rand within the scope. Example:

```
(with-rand-seed 9
  (rand 4)       ; => 2.9206461906433105
  (rand-int 10)) ; => 2
```

BTW. Beware of lazy seqs: http://kotka.de/blog/2009/11/Taming_the_Bound_Seq.html (Apparently, this link redirects to https without a trusted certificate so here's a link to a version at Web Archive: https://web.archive.org/web/20120505012701/http://kotka.de/blog/2009/11/Taming_the_Bound_Seq.html).

Comment: Probably not suitable for my need, but it's interesting, and might be useful for someone else.  Why does the function this combination of `let`, `binding`, and `with-redefs`?  (`:use emotion.examples` doesn't seem to be needed, btw.) (Why is kotka.de redirecting to the same url with "https" substituted?  That makes browsers complain the the connection is untrusted.)

Comment: Thanks for the heads up; I edited the post. The `let` isn't necessary, this is a leftover from the more complicated version of the macro I actually use (along with 'emotion.examples' which I use for inline specs *lol*). The `redef` is there to wrap the dynamic var in a function because `clojure.core/rand` has multiple arities so I couldn't use `*rand*` directly.

Comment: any idea how to use that with test generators ?

Answer (score 3):

Clojure's `rand` relies on the `random` method in `java.lang.Math`:

```
user=> (source rand)
(defn rand
  "Returns a random floating point number between 0 (inclusive) and
  n (default 1) (exclusive)."
  {:added "1.0"
   :static true}
  ([] (. Math (random)))
  ([n] (* n (rand))))
```

According to the Oracle Java 7 documentation at https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#random()

> public static double random()
>
> Returns a double value with a positive sign, greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0. Returned values are chosen pseudorandomly with (approximately) uniform distribution from that range.
>
> When this method is first called, it creates a single new pseudorandom-number generator, exactly as if by the expression
>
> new java.util.Random()
>
> This new pseudorandom-number generator is used thereafter for all calls to this method and is used nowhere else.
>
> This method is properly synchronized to allow correct use by more than one thread. However, if many threads need to generate pseudorandom numbers at a great rate, it may reduce contention for each thread to have its own pseudorandom-number generator.
>
> Returns:
>
> a pseudorandom double greater than or equal to 0.0 and less than 1.0.

If you browse the `java.lang.Math` documentation, you will see that it does not have an API to allow setting of a random number generator seed. Code using the `random()` API does not get the ability to set the seed or hold onto different copies of the random number generator.

The original question was:

> I want to be able to generate repeatable numbers using rand in Clojure.
>   [e.g. clojure.core/rand]

This is not possible, unless you use your own rand function. So, instead of `clojure.core/rand`, I suggesting using [clojure.data.generators](https://github.com/clojure/data.generators) which exposes the random number generator as a dynamic var `*rnd*`:

```
(def ^:dynamic ^java.util.Random
     *rnd*
     "Random instance for use in generators. By consistently using this
instance you can get a repeatable basis for tests."
     (java.util.Random. 42))
```

Use `gen/*rnd*` as shown in this example:

```
(require '[clojure.data.generators :as gen])
(binding [gen/*rnd* (java.util.Random. 12345)]
  (gen/int))
```

This always returns `-593551136`.

Answer (score 2):

Here's how you might define the function generator that you can seed that I described in the comments.

If you don't want doubles, see the [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html).

```
user=> (defn randfn
  #_=>   ([] (randfn (java.util.Random.)))
  #_=>   ([r] #(.nextDouble r)))
#'user/randfn
user=> (def source1 (randfn))
#'user/source1
user=> (source1)
0.6270662940925175
user=> (source1)
0.23351789802762046
```

Here's how you might create it with a seeded Random number generator.

```
user=> (def source2 (randfn (java.util.Random. 37)))
#'user/source2
user=> (take 3 (repeatedly #(source2)))
(0.7276532767062343 0.5136790759391296 0.7384220244718898)

user=> (def source3 (randfn (java.util.Random. 37)))
#'user/source3
user=> (take 3 (repeatedly #(source3)))
(0.7276532767062343 0.5136790759391296 0.7384220244718898
```

As a bonus, you could also use the newish [ThreadLocalRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadLocalRandom.html) or the not very new at all [SecureRandom](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) as your random number generators.

```
user=> (def secure-source (randfn (java.security.SecureRandom.)))
#'user/secure-source
user=> (take 3 (repeatedly #(secure-source)))
(0.9987555822097023 0.48452119609266475 0.443029180668418)
```

Answer (score 2):

just wanted to add, for anyone still looking at this, there is already a library on clojars since 2015 that does this:

https://github.com/trystan/random-seed

Answer (score 1):

In the original question, two things are misunderstood:

- How to use dynamic vars
- How to use clojure.data.generators

First, dynamic vars should be managed via the `binding` macro. Second `rand` is not a function of `clojure.data.generators`, but of `clojure.core` itself and thus resetting the `*rnd*` var doesn't have effect. So here is how you should do it:

```lisp
(require '[clojure.data.generators :as gen])

(binding [gen/*rnd* (java.util.Random. 437)]
  (println (gen/double)) ;=> 0.7634858067742888
  (println (gen/double)) ;=> 0.6959205688388975
  )

(binding [gen/*rnd* (java.util.Random. 437)]
  (println (gen/double)) ;=> 0.7634858067742888
  (println (gen/double)) ;=> 0.6959205688388975
  )
```

Comment: Thanks Jeroen.  I used `alter-var-root` rather than `bind` because I was using the RNG in a few different places in the code, in different files.  It wouldn't have made sense to use different RNGs for each of them; I'd have to store multiple seeds.  (Though I guess could generate the RNGs from seeds generated by an RNG, which I did, later, in other parts of the code.)   I eventually used one of [Sean Luke's](http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~sean/research/) [Java versions of the Mersenne Twister algorithm](http://www.cs.gmu.edu/~sean/research/mersenne/MersenneTwisterFast.java), so no need for `bind`.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, none of the above are functional approaches. If you want that, you can use a lazy-seq:

```
(letfn [(f [randomizer]  (lazy-seq (cons (.nextInt randomizer) (f randomizer))))]
  (defn create-random 
    ([] (f (java.util.Random.)))
    ([seed] (f (java.util.Random. seed)))))
```

To get the first random number you use:

```
(first (create-random 0)) ;; using 0 as seed
```

To get the rest of the sequence you use:

```
(rest (create-random 0)) ;; again 0 as seed
```

To get the first element and a reference to the rest you can use:

```
(defn pop [x (create-random 0)]
     (n, rest) `(~(first x) ~(rest x)))
```

Comment: As coded, the random number generator can't be functional; it has to have internal state.  That's how it can generate a new number every time with every call to `.nextInt`.  Using a lazy sequence might be useful in some context, but I don't think that by itself it makes the process functional.  It's possible to have a random number generator that doesn't store state; then you have to pass in the state from the previous call.  (Also, it's often considered bad form to call `defn` inside a `let`--although there's a time and place for everything.)

Comment: The alternative would be wrapping the randomiser in a linked list with elements where each element holds the result of a call to the randomiser and a pointer to the element which holds the next result and so forth. Essentially, the call to java.util.Random will never be referentially transparent if you don't pass in a seed. But I guess, that's the point of Random.